# Python: How do I print out values with their corresponding keys and sort them?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key

My code is supposed to create another dictionary out of the existing dictionary of synonyms, with synonyms 7 or fewer characters removed, using the function called remove_word() and taking the existing dictionary as the parameter. It should return a new dictionary with updated values like this:

```
{'slow' : ['leisurely', 'unhurried'], 'show' : ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'], 'dangerous' : ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain']}
```

With the key_order() function, I would want to produce a list of keys and use the sort() method to sort the keys in alphabetical order, then loop through the sorted keys and print out its corresponding values.

The output should look like this sorted in alphabetical order:

```
dangerous : ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain']
show : ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose']
slow : ['leisurely', 'unhurried']
```

How can I complete this without using complicated syntax?

The code:

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
             'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
             'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

def main():
    edited_synonyms = remove_word(word_dict)
    key_order(edited_synonyms)

def remove_word(word_dict):
    dictionary = {}

    synonyms_list = word_dict.values()
    new_list = []
    for i in synonyms_list:
        new_list.append(i)

    for word in new_list:
        letter_length = len(word)
        if letter_length <= 7:
            new_list.pop(new_list.index(word))

    value = new_list 
    keys_only = word_dict.keys()
    key = keys_only
    dictionary[key] = value
    return dictionary


def key_order(word_dict):
    word_list = list(word_dict.keys())
    word_list.sort()
    for letter in word_list:
        value = word_list[letter]
        print(letter, ": ", value)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary and list comprehensions for achieving this

```
word_dict = {'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'convey', 'communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose'],
         'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 'slack'],
         'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

new_word_dict = {k:[l for l in v if len(l) > 7] for k,v in word_dict.items()}
for key in sorted(new_word_dict.keys()):
    print(f"{key} : {new_word_dict[key]}")
```

Output

```
dangerous : ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']
show : ['communicate', 'manifest', 'disclose']
slow : ['unhurried', 'leisurely']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through it:

```
for x in dict.keys():
    print(f'{x}: {dict[x]}')
```